# Little clarification on Gallagher's Larger Sieve

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

[image]
[image]

**Edit :**

> After multiplication the inequality by $\Lambda (t)$ and then sum over $t\in \mathscr{T}$ we get ,
>   $\displaystyle \sum_{t\in \mathscr{T}}\frac{(\#B)^2}{u(t)}\Lambda(t)\le (\#B)\sum_{t\in \mathscr{T}}\Lambda (t)+\sum_{b,b'\in B\\b\not=b'}\sum_{t\in \mathscr{T}}\Lambda(t)\sum_{t|(b-b')}1$.
>
> I take only the last term of the R.H.S. and rewrite it as: 
>   $\displaystyle \sum_{b,b'\in B\\b\not=b'}\sum_{t\in \mathscr{T}}\sum_{t|(b-b')}\Lambda(t)=\sum_{b,b'\in B\\b\not=b'}\sum_{t\in \mathscr{T}}\log(b-b')\le \log(X).\sum_{b,b'\in B\\b\not=b'}\sum_{t\in \mathscr{T}}1$.
>
> How it comes $\log(2X).((\#B)^2-\#B)$ in the last line ?

Comment: That's rather difficult to read. But it looks like (2) follows from (1) just by squaring.

Comment: As Lord said and $Z(B;t,r)^2 = \sum_{b,b' \equiv r \bmod t} 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\#B \leq u(t)^{\frac12} \left( \sum_{r \pmod t} Z(b,t,r)^2\right)^\frac12$$

Squaring and dividing by $u(t)$, we have

$$\frac{(\#B)^2}{u(t)} \leq \sum_{r \pmod t} Z(b,t,r)^2$$

\begin{align}
Z(B,t,r)^2 &= \left( \sum_{b \in B, b \equiv r \pmod t}  1\right)^2 \\
&= \left( \sum_{b \in B, b \equiv r \pmod t}  1\right)\left( \sum_{b' \in B, b' \equiv r \pmod t}  1\right) \\
&= \sum_{b,b' \in B \\b,b' \equiv r \pmod t}
1\end{align}
Edit to explain the next line:
\begin{align}\sum_{r \pmod t} \sum_{b,b' \in B \\b,b' \equiv r \pmod t}
1  &= \sum_{r \pmod t} \left(  \sum_{b \in B \\ b \equiv r \pmod t} 1+ \sum_{b,b' \in B , b \neq b' \\b,b' \equiv r \pmod t}
1 \right) \\
&= \sum_{r \pmod t}   \sum_{b \in B \\ b \equiv r \pmod t} 1+\sum_{r \pmod t} \sum_{b,b' \in B , b \neq b' \\b,b' \equiv r \pmod t}
1 \\
&= \sum_{r \pmod t}   Z(B,t,r)+ \sum_{b,b' \in B , b \neq b' \\b' \equiv b \pmod t}
1 \\
&= \#B + \sum_{b , b' \in B \\ b \neq b' } \sum_{t|b-b'}1\end{align}

Edit to answer the edit:

\begin{align}\displaystyle \sum_{b,b'\in B\\b\not=b'}\sum_{t\in \mathscr{T}}\sum_{t|(b-b')}\Lambda(t)&=\sum_{b,b'\in B\\b\not=b'}\log(|b-b'|)\\&\le \log(2X).\sum_{b,b'\in B\\b\not=b'}1 \\
&= \log(2X) ((\#B)^2 - \#B) \end{align}

Comment: Yes. I got it just few minutes ago.. But still not getting how the next inequality comes just after equation 2. Can you make clear to me ?

Comment: Edited, they seems to separate the case when $b=b'$ and $b \neq b'$

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. If you don't mind can I ask you an another question ? Can you please see my edited question ?

Comment: Edited. note that $b-b'$ does take negative value, hence absolute value is needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot..!